# Problems with ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, server-side, vps

Just find this lovely place and would like to share my experience.
Probably I will not be able to specify my questions correctly so please forgive me in advance.

I am not a coder and don't understand almost nothing from programming. My power is marketing and seo, and project management. 
I own a web site build in php and mysql and hired service provider to implement custom video feature using ffmpeg to convert it on the fly. They did it and the script worked on their server. My old host didn't supported ffmpeg and I switched to VPS. Coders offered me to evaluate their server as well, but much more expensive. I am easy going and friendly person and have paid the price before to see this working on my server - I know, my mistake.

And so 15 days already I am in doubt. Coders says that VPS is not managed and configured properly, server support says that all systems and extensions work correctly.

My question (may take is stupid) how to understand who lies me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Coders should bring some provements like errorlogs or failures to show that the server is not configuered properly. If you can see that entry X in the errorlogs turns out that the server is misconfigured, you know how lies to you. If they cannot bring you any provements, they might lie to you. Nevertheless hard to answer this question

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, much appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

May be they are not laying but the script may work in php and ffmpeg version doesn't compatible with your VPS, ask your developers to give you full environment report about where the script had been tested.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, much appreciate your answers.